# How do I apply the finite difference method to a torsion equation?

Tags: numerical-methods, finite-differences, finite-difference-methods

So I've previously used the method to determine temperature across a thin plate. But my textbook doesn't what to do when the second derivates of space (x and y) are equal to a function.

I'm trying to use the first order aproximation to determine tortion through a prismatic bar. Here is the specific question:

> Problems of elastic torsion of prismatic bars are reprsented
>   mathematicallly by the equation:
>
> $T_{xx}$ is the second order partial derivative of T with respect to
>   x.
>
> $T_{xx} - T_{yy} = -2G\theta$
>
> Where $G$ is the elastic shear modulus and $\theta$ is the angle of
>   twist for each section. The function T is the stress function, defined
>   as T = 0 on the boundaries.
>
> Consider a bar of rectangular cross section with dimensions 30cm by
>   30cm. Use the finite difference method to find the value of the stress
>   functionT at all internal nodal points of the bar, adopting a step
>   length $\Delta x=\Delta y=h=10cm$ assume values G = 0.01 and $\theta =2x$.
>   Generate a system of equations and solve for each internal node.

This is a laplace example I'd been given previously + my attempt for a Poisson equation. I'm particularly unsure about the h**2 coefficient. There aren't examples of solutions to: second orders space derivatives = function.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/boHII.png

Would appreciate any help. Even if it's a, "Yep keep doing that".

Comment: Yeah, seems fine

Comment: @David thanks!!

Comment: @RoryMcDonald I just want to point out a typo in your *png file (sign of T_{yy})

Comment: @Albe Oh yeah fixed now. ty